# SQL most recent order? MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im just writing a query to look through my clients customers database and to list how many orders they have made etc.

What I'm struggling to add into this query is to only show me most recent OrderID for that email

Any ideas?

Here is my query

```
select top 1000 
     BuyerEMail
     ,COUNT(*) HowMany
     ,Name
from Orders 
where 
     Pay != 'PayPal'
group by 
     BuyerEmail
     ,Name
order by 
     HowMany Desc
```

Comment: it depends on how you define the most recent order? do you have a date in your table?

Comment: Yes we have OrderDate column. I wasn also thinking of doing FirstOrDefault but you can't in SQL...

Comment: Have you a table with buyer list?

Comment: Please share the structure of the involved tables, Some sample data, expected output and the problem you faced when you tried to solve this problem. The more you help us, the more accurate we can help. Hint: [FIRST_VALUE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx)

Comment: [Do a search for greatest n per group and sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql-server?sort=votes&pageSize=50) N in your case is 1

Comment: @Pred First_Value is fine if you're looking for a single value (e.g. orderid) but people usually want the whole record

Comment: @ConradFrix `only show me most recent OrderID for that email` << From the question. If the OP can not share what are the real requirements, we can not provide accurate solutions. Since the question states that one column is required, I chose the hint to get that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go;

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
o.BuyerEMail
,COUNT(*) HowMany
,o.Name
,o2.OrderID
FROM Orders o
JOIN 
    (
     SELECT 
     BuyerEmail
     ,MAX(OrderDate) Latest 
     FROM Orders 
     GROUP BY BuyerEmail
    ) l
ON o.BuyerEmail = l.BuyerEmail

JOIN Orders o2
ON l.BuyerEmail = o2.BuyerEmail
AND l.OrderDate = o2.OrderDate

WHERE Pay != 'PayPal'

GROUP BY 
    o.BuyerEmail
    ,o.Name
    ,l.Latest
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

It works out the latest order by each email address in a sub query, you can then use this in the SELECT. I've also aliased the tables to make things easier.

You can do this another way too, by nesting subqueries;

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
o.BuyerEMail
,COUNT(*) HowMany
,o.Name
,o2.OrderID
FROM Orders o
JOIN 
    (
     SELECT
     BuyerEmail
     ,OrderID
     FROM
     Orders ord
     JOIN
        (
            SELECT 
            BuyerEmail
            ,MAX(OrderDate) Latest 
            FROM Orders 
            GROUP BY BuyerEmail
        ) ma
     ON ord.BuyerEmail = ma.BuyerEmail
     AND ord.OrderDate = ma.OrderDate
    ) l
ON o.BuyerEmail = l.BuyerEmail

WHERE Pay != 'PayPal'

GROUP BY 
    o.BuyerEmail
    ,o.Name
    ,l.Latest
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: This works but instead of displaying the OrderDate I would like to display the OrderID that goes with it. I've tried adding it into that JOIN but get an error.. Do I need a seperate Join to add OrderID from the latest date?

Comment: You could yeah, or you could nest another sub query. I've updated my answer with another join to the orders table (o2) to bring back this info. This will work best if you have a datetime field in order date.

Comment: Did this one get it sorted for you?

Comment: It works thank you :) Sorry for late response I was renaming columns :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are having troubles writing sql queries, try to break up your needs into single statements.

First you wanted the number of orders per buyer, which you already solved.

```
SELECT BuyerEMail
, Name
, COUNT(*) as TotalOrders
FROM Orders
WHERE Pay <> 'PayPal'
GROUP BY BuyerEmail, Name
Order By TotalOrders Desc
```

Now you wanted to display the latest order for each buyer. Something like this would do:

```
SELECT BuyerEMail
, Name
, MAX(OrderDate) LatestOrder
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY BuyerEmail, Name
```

Next, you need to combine your output to one statement. If you compare the two statements, both are grouped by the same set (Buyer and Name), so you could sum it up to:

```
SELECT BuyerEMail
, Name
, COUNT(*) as TotalOrders
, MAX(OrderDate) LatestOrder
FROM Orders
WHERE Pay <> 'PayPal'
GROUP BY BuyerEmail, Name
```

If you only want to count the orders having Pay != 'PayPal', you could do:

```
SELECT BuyerEMail
, Name
, COUNT(CASE WHEN Pay != 'PayPal' THEN 1 END) as TotalOrders
, MAX(OrderDate) LatestOrder
FROM Orders
GROUP BY BuyerEmail, Name
```

Now you commented you would also want the OrderID for the latest Order. A Lead() function in sqlserver 2012+ could do, a subselect or how I prefer a cross apply:

```
SELECT o.*
, OrderID as LastOrderID
, OrderDate as LastOrderDate
FROM (
    SELECT BuyerEMail
    , Name
    , COUNT(*) as TotalOrders
    FROM Orders
    WHERE Pay != 'PayPal'
    GROUP BY BuyerEmail, Name
) o
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 OrderID, OrderDate
    FROM Orders s
    WHERE s.BuyerEmail = o.BuyerEmail
    ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
) ca
```

As you can see, things become easier if you split it up in smaller logical parts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
     BuyerEMail
     ,COUNT(*) HowMany
     ,Name
FROM Orders O
     JOIN (Select Max(OrderDate) LastOrder, BuyerEmail From Orders Group By BuyerEmail) R On R.BuyerEmail = O.BuyerEmail
WHERE 
     Pay != 'PayPal'
GROUP BY 
     BuyerEmail
     ,Name
ORDER BY 
     HowMany Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table has a date or datetime field You can order by this field desc, so you gonna view the most recent orders, otherwise if you don't have any date field in your table, but instead of it you have an incremental id and your fields are increasing and there are only insertions, you can use your primary key as desc too.
I strong recommend to use data field in your table if you don't have anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this if I understood correctly?

```
;with cte as (
    select BuyerEMail, lastOrderId = Max(OrderId) 
    from Orders
    group by BuyerEMail
),
cte1 as (
    select BuyerEMail, ordersCount = count(*) 
    from orders 
    where ( pay != 'paypal' ) 
    group By BuyerEMail
)
select
    a.lastOrderId, a.BuyerEMail, b.ordersCount
from
    cte as a
    inner join cte1 as b on ( a.BuyerEMail = b.BuyerEMail )
```