# SQL add STUFF function into this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    o.BuyerEMail,
    COUNT(*) HowMany,
    o.Name, o2.OrderID
FROM 
    Orders o
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         BuyerEmail, MAX(OrderDate) Latest 
     FROM Orders 
     GROUP BY BuyerEmail) l ON o.BuyerEmail = l.BuyerEmail
JOIN 
    Orders o2 ON l.BuyerEmail = o2.BuyerEmail
              AND l.OrderDate = o2.OrderDate
WHERE 
    Pay != 'PayPal'
GROUP BY 
    o.BuyerEmail, o.Name, l.Latest
ORDER BY
```

It's just producing a report about customers and how many orders they have with us and the latest order.

What I want to add is a list of the products of their last order which are in lines table.

Lines table is linked to order table by `OrderID`.

I was looking for something like:

```
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         OrderID,
         STUFF((SELECT ', ' + li.Code
                FROM tblLines li
                WHERE li.OrderID = o2.OrderID 
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS [Codes]
GROUP BY
    OrderID, Code
```

So the final table displays as

```
BuyerEmail | HowMany | Name | Latest | Codes
---------------------------------------------
Bob@bob    | 4       | bob  | 10000  | 123,10,201231
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you posted the query from another question ([SQL most recent order? MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324365/sql-most-recent-order-ms-sql)), I will use my answer as it is cleaner than the above query:

```
SELECT o.*
, OrderID as LastOrderID
FROM (
    SELECT BuyerEMail
    , Name
    , COUNT(*) as TotalOrders
    FROM Orders
    WHERE Pay != 'PayPal'
    GROUP BY BuyerEmail, Name
) o
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 OrderID, OrderDate
    FROM Orders s
    WHERE s.BuyerEmail = o.BuyerEmail
    ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
) ca
```

You posted a good example, it wasn't complete thou. You would need the following xmlpath query:

```
SELECT OrderID
, Codes
FROM tblLines r1
CROSS APPLY ( 
    SELECT
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(Code AS NVARCHAR)
        FROM tblLines r2
        WHERE r2.OrderID = r1.OrderID
        GROUP BY OrderID, Code
        ORDER BY Code
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE)
        .value('.', 'varchar(max)')
        , 1, 1, ''))  OrderLines(Codes)
GROUP BY OrderID, OrderList
```

Add it to the previous statement with a simple join:

```
SELECT  o.BuyerEMail
    ,o.Name
    ,o.TotalOrders
    , OrderID as LastOrderID
    , c.Codes
FROM (
        SELECT BuyerEMail
        , Name
        , COUNT(*) as TotalOrders
        FROM Orders
        WHERE Pay != 'PayPal'
        GROUP BY BuyerEmail, Name
) o
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 OrderID, OrderDate
        FROM Orders s
        WHERE s.BuyerEmail = o.BuyerEmail
        ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
) ca 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT OrderID
    , Codes
    FROM tblLines r1
    CROSS APPLY ( 
        SELECT
            STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(Code AS NVARCHAR)
            FROM tblLines r2
            WHERE r2.OrderID = r1.OrderID
            GROUP BY OrderID, Code
            ORDER BY Code
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE)
            .value('.', 'varchar(max)')
            , 1, 1, ''))  OrderLines(Codes)
    GROUP BY OrderID, OrderList
) c
ON ca.OrderID = c.OrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
o.BuyerEMail,
COUNT(*) HowMany,
o.Name, l.Latest,
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + li.Code
            FROM tblLines li
            WHERE li.OrderID = o2.OrderID 
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS [Codes]
```

FROM 
    Orders o
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         BuyerEmail, MAX(OrderDate) Latest 
     FROM Orders 
     GROUP BY BuyerEmail) l ON o.BuyerEmail = l.BuyerEmail
JOIN 
    Orders o2 ON l.BuyerEmail = o2.BuyerEmail
              AND l.OrderDate = o2.OrderDate
WHERE 
    Pay != 'PayPal'
GROUP BY 
    o.BuyerEmail, o.Name, l.Latest
ORDER BY